# What font is used for TeenChat's logo?

Tags: font-identification

I've tried using some font identifier websites but none come back with a match.

Does someone know what font is used here?

[image]

**Source:** http://www.teenchat.com

Comment: There's enough variation in the two 'E's to assume that this was hand lettered (or a modified version of an existing typeface).

Comment: Have you ever tried using the [Whatthefont](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) image scanner. It can usually get you in the ballpark of a certain font used in images.

Answer (score 1):

I think this what a hand made logo, by which I mean there is no defined font used. I think this is lines used to create letters. It reminds me a bit of the old [Toon Town logo](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/3/33/Toontown-Logo.svg/377px-Toontown-Logo.svg.png)
[image]